# Which Windows version should I install as guest OS on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I want to install Windows on VirtualBox on my Ubuntu laptop to be able to run some Windows applications. However, I'm not sure which Windows version I should install to get the best performances. I'd like the guest OS to be lightweight and fast booting. I hesitate between Xindows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (I have access to licences for all those versions). Should I install 32 or 64 bits version? What are the pros and cons for each choice?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is likely too broad for a one-size-fits-all answer.  "Performances" vary based on input and desires for output.  Optimizing for fast booting is only wise if you plan to boot often.  I'm going to guess that's not a planned likely scenario for you.  Asking for the pros and cons of each choice is asking a lot for not much gain.  None of the choices are abjectly horrible.

For most situations, I would install XP for the general case of "to be able to run some Windows applications" in a vm.  Newer versions offer more than you need for the task and KISS applies, as ever.  32-bit XP is still the most widely installed version of Windows in the business world.  Things have a higher chance of just working how you'd expect.  If you find you want something that another Windows version has, cross that bridge when you get to it.  I doubt you're limited to one vm :)

Roll up your sleeves and dig in.  Have fun!